# Infinite amount of vertical asymptotes

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

Is it possible that the graph of function has infinitely many vertical asymptotes?

I suppose, that it is not possible, because such function would not exist. But I need to prove it in a math-fashioned-way, and I'm clueless how to do it.

Help would be appreciated. :) Thanks.

Comment: $\tan x{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Oh yes, that indeed has infinitely many asymptotes. Still, how do I prove that in a math-way?

Comment: We can even have the asymptotes accumulate in the finite. $f(x)=\sum_n\frac1{(nx-1)2^n}$ has a definition gap with vertical asymptote at all $\frac 1n$, while it is defined (i.e., converges) everywhere else

Comment: @weno I'd say that *TonyK*'s comment is a "math-way" proof of the claim

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Do I simply answer the question with "yes, because for example f(x) = tan x has infinitely many vertical asymptotes"?

Comment: @weno: Yes. You might add "at all odd multiples of $\pi/2$", or some such.

Comment: "how do I prove that in a math-way ?": you do it the same way you find a single vertical asymptote, and with $\tan x$ the equations will naturally lead you to an infinity of solutions.

Comment: " because such function would not exist": which intuition makes you say that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a function has a vertical asymptote at $x$ when it can be expressed as: $f(x)=\frac{a}{g(x)}\mid a\neq g(x)$ and $g(x)=0$, the simplest example of which is $\frac{1}{x}$.

For a function to have *infinitely* many vertical asymptotes there must be infinitely many values of $x$ for which $g(x)=0$. There are two ways this can happen:

(1.) $g(x)$ is periodic with infinitely many zeros - i.e.
$$f(x)=u\frac{1}{per(x)}\mid per:=\sin,\cos,\tan,\mod,\ldots,etc.$$
(2.) $f(x)$ is a sum or product of an infinite series.

The latter case is pretty much the same as the former, as most (if not all) such infinite series have a closed form solution equivalent to (1.), for example:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)!}{x^{2n+1}}$$ is just the inverse of the Taylor series for the $\sin$ function.

As TonK commented, $\tan{x}$ is a straightforward example. You could also use $\frac{u}{\sin{x}}$, $\frac{u}{\cos{x}}$, $\Gamma(x)$, etc.

Comment: Hello, thanks for sending this! I have one question though. :) In the first sentence, did you mean that g(x) = 0 or g(x) =/= 0? :) Confused here.

Comment: I have one more question: what is the $ u $ in the first example?

Comment: I did mean $g(x)=0$, basically, this is why you're not supposed to divide by 0, and why some people claim that $1/0=\infty$. As for $u$, it can be whatever you want it to be - a constant, another function of $x$ - as long as it isn't equal to whatever's in the denominator (because then $f(x)$ would be 1).

Comment: This answer is terribly muddled! "There are two ways this can happen"? Where did that come from?

Comment: Generally, any problem involving an infinite amount of something can be solved using an infinite series. There are two ways because it is intuitively obvious that $\tan{x}$ has infinitely many vertical asymptotes, but arbitrarily complicated functions can be built using infinite sums.